# Is it possible to have underlines at the same height in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, underline

For my thesis, I would like to use (light gray) underlines to indicate the rank of tensors. There are three modes: No underline, one underline and two underline. (For rank-0, rank-1 and rank-2 tensors.)

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: example for underlines]

Since the underlines are not essential, they should not disturb the reader. But I do not like, that the underlines are all at different heights.

For example

```
$\underline{\underline{G}}, \underline{\underline{g}}$
```

results in

[image: different heights]

**Is there an easy way to have the underlines all the the same height?**

I would not mind, if the underlines are in the background and the letters might overlap them a bit...

---

I know, underlines are an ugly idea, but in elasticity, there are many variables to keep in mind. Therefore, I would like to support the reader at least a little bit. But if I do not find a good notation, I will just drop the idea.

I don't want to use `\mathbb` or other too fancy font modes. (These are sometimes used to denote rank-4 tensors already.)
I can not use lower or upper case to distinguish them, since this already indicates the domains and I want to stay close to my literature.

Comment: Here's the easy way: `$\underline{\underline{\vphantom{g}G}}, \underline{\underline{g}}$` or `$\underline{\underline{G}}, \underline{\underline{\smash{g}}}$`

Comment: That's exactly what I looked for! This answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a syntax that you can change easily, so define commands for what you want. Here are some options:

```
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\something}{\bm}
\newcommand{\suline}[1]{\underline{#1}}
\newcommand{\duline}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
```

The above provides `\something` (whatever your use-case would be for printing elements in **bold**) and two underline macros: `\suline` that adds a `s`ingle `u`nder`line` and `\duline` for `d`ouble `u`nder`line`s.

If you want all underlines to be at the same level, you could try using:

```
\newcommand{\suline}[1]{\underline{\vphantom{\mathstrut}#1}}
\newcommand{\duline}[1]{\underline{\underline{\vphantom{\mathstrut}#1}}}
```

`\mathstrut` is a box of "typical" height/depth.

Comment: I actually like the `\smash` solution most ;)  But `\mathstrut` is also a useful command here.